# Grabbing the max value from my MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb

I need to return the player_id with the most total ipouts from my data structure. Here's what I need to do in pseudocode:

```
1. Add together all ipouts for each player
2. Grab the max ipouts
3. Display the player_id of the one with max ipouts
```

So far I have number one correct. This correctly lists each player ID and their total number of ipouts.

```
db.pitching.aggregate([ 
    { $group: 
        { _id: "$player_id", ipouts: 
            { $sum: "$ipouts" }
        }
     }
]);
```

Now the next step is to get the max. This is where I'm struggling:

```
db.pitching.aggregate([ 
    { $group: 
        { _id: "$player_id", ipouts: 
            { $sum: "$ipouts" }
        }
    },
    { $group: 
        { _id: "$_id" , max: { $max: "$ipouts"} }
    }
]);
```

Some other questions I've checked out don't work, as I know I need to use aggregate which means I cannot do a sort/limit(1). I've also tried setting the `_id` to `null`, which didn't work either. This code is returning an empty array (if i add `toArray()` I can see the empty brackets).

How can I get the PlayerID of the object with the maximum ipouts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate has its own version of sort and limit via the [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) and [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) pipeline operators. So you can do this as:

```
db.pitching.aggregate([ 
    { $group: 
        { _id: "$player_id", ipouts: 
            { $sum: "$ipouts" }
        }
    },
    { $sort: {ipouts: -1 } },
    { $limit: 1 }
]);
```